# unable to run tensorboard from command line to evaluate the efficiency of my model

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

while running tensorboard command i'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'equal'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/bin/tensorboard", line 6, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import c_api_util
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/c_api_util.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import compat
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 129, in <module>
    integral_types = (_numbers.Integral, _np.integer)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'integer'
```

i tried updating numpy using :

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade numpy
```

AND

```
conda update numpy
```

but getting the same error again

i ran this command:
`tensorboard --logdir=training/`

Comment: You should show the actual code.

Comment: Which code you want me to show?